# Numpy choose: shape-mismatch error

Tags: python, numpy

I wish to shuffle between two pairs of numpy arrays, for example given

```
a = [a1,a2,a3,a4]
a_next = [a2,a3,a4,a5]
b = [b1,b2,b3,b4]
b_next [b2,b3,b4,b5]
```

I want to shuffle between a and b to get

```
x = [a1,b2,b3,a4]
x_next = [a2,b3,b4,a5]
y = [b1,a2,a3,b4]
y_next = [b2,a3,a4,b5]
```

I have managed to get this working for single-dimensional a and b, using:

```
a = np.array([11,22,33,44])
a_next = np.array([22,33,44,55])
b = np.array([10,20,30,40])
b_next = np.array([20,30,40,50])

choices = [a,b]
choices_next = [a_next,b_next]
alternating_indices = np.random.randint(0, 2, len(a)) # Random 0s or 1s

x = np.choose(alternating_indices, choices)
x_next = np.choose(alternating_indices, choices_next)
y = np.choose(1-alternating_indices, choices)
y_next = np.choose(1-alternating_indices, choices_next)
```

But my real a and b are actually 3D arrays (so a1, a2, ..., b1, b2 are of shape `[width, height]`) which gives the error `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`. Here's a toy example which gives the same error:

```
a = np.array([[11,11],[22,22],[33,33],[44,44]])
a_next = np.array([[22,22],[33,33],[44,44],[55,55]])
b = np.array([[10,10],[20,20],[30,30],[40,40]])
b_next = np.array([[20,20],[30,30],[40,40],[50,50]])
```

So, how can I make this work for arrays with elements of non-trivial shape? The real arrays a, a_next, b and b_next are of equal shape `[M, width, height]`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I thought about that, but using a boolean array I would be able to choose between "a or nothing" and "b or nothing", but I want to choose "a or b". Is there a way to do this using boolean arrays?

Comment: You're right! I hadn't thought about using the boolean indexing on the left hand side of the assignment as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use boolean indexing on the first axis. The following

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[11,11],[22,22],[33,33],[44,44]])
b = np.array([[10,10],[20,20],[30,30],[40,40]])
ind = np.random.randint(0, 2, len(a), dtype=np.bool)

a[ind,...], b[ind,...] = b[ind,...], a[ind,...]

print(a)
print(b)
```

gives

```
[[10 10]
 [22 22]
 [33 33]
 [40 40]]
[[11 11]
 [20 20]
 [30 30]
 [44 44]]
```

for, in this case,

```
ind = [ True False False  True]
```

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: You can concatenate the arrays that interest you, then shuffle them and slice them:

```
c = np.concatenate((a, b))
np.random.shuffle(c)
x, y = c[:N], c[N:]
```

Slightly longer explanation:

From the arrays `a` and `b` you can create `c = np.concatenate((a, b))` that returns the array `c = np.array([a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, b3, b4])`, then shuffle it in place using the function `np.random.shuffle(c)`. Now c will look something like `c = np.array([a3, b1, a2, b2, a4, a1, b3, b4])`. Finally, You can create the arrays x and y by slicing c in two parts. Assuming that the length of the array x you want to create is N < M, the array x can be created doing `x = c[:N]` and y by `y = c[N:]`.

Comment: Actually, in your code, x and y always contain 2 elements from a and 2 from b. However, you didn't mention it as a requirement. Please notice that the solution I proposed doesn't guarantee that.